# Use console.log in EJS

Tags: node.js, console, ejs

Is it possible to use console.log in a node / ejs template? It doesn't seem to do anything when I try, even something as simple as:

```
<% console.log('test') %>
```

I've also tried:

```
<%= console.log('test') %>
```

Nothing shows up in the console.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are expecting it to show in the developer console. It will not show up there.
`console.log()` in EJS file will show the log in the terminal where the server is running.

Answer (score 6):

This worked perfectly

`<% console.log('heheeh', JSON.stringify(doc, null, '\t')) %>`

Comment: What do you mean here?

Answer (score 4):

`console.log()` is working fine, but its log does not display in dev tools.
So, check your terminal first:

```
<% console.log("test") %>
```

It's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log(test)` in `ejs` file will show the log in the terminal

And if you want to see test object or value in browser than try

```
<%= test %>
```

This will show objects as string

Answer (score 1):

first, Your home route inside your index.js/server.js/app.js, render a variable you want console log in another ejs file; in the code below, nposts is a variable or an array;

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.render("home", {posts: nposts});
```

then in your ejs file, in this example in the home.ejs console.log in the <% %> tags

```
<% console.log(posts); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, but I just had this issue and this is what I ended up doing:

```
<% var data = JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin) %>
<script>
  console.log(<%= data %>)
</script>
```

It doesn't look pretty, but it works

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmeCi.png)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuctQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <% console.log(posts) %>
```

NB: Make sure you define your variable in any other file you have eg app.js file...

```html
let posts = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home", {
        posts: posts
    });
});
```

**OUTPUT**
[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4iPK.png)

Answer (score 0):

### send from serve-side

```
let item = [arr1, arr2, arr3]

res.send("index", { item })
```

### in client-side

###### example

use in script

```
console.log('<%- item %'>
```

> arr1,arr2,arr3

```
console.log('<%- JSON.stringify( item ) '%>
```

> ["arr1","arr2","arr3"]      //text

```
var newArray = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify( item )%>')
  
console.log(newArray )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer would be:

If you are in your home route and you want to test any condition you would have to use ejs tags. inside the tags drop your normal console.log.

`<% console.log(test) %>`